# Kendo Grid Date format validation not working

Tags: php, laravel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Why is that only the field name shows when i enter invalid formats. Eventhough ive tried different validation styles it still shows if the format is invalid. I've created custom validation already but it only works if the date is empty or null but if it is not it does not work it is because when i enter wrong format in the field the custom validation does not work .

[image of the actual validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egsJg.png)

here is the code

```
$('#lot-sched-grid').kendoGrid({
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "maintenance/sales/s-lot-sched/read-header/0",
                    dataType: "json"
                },              
                update: {
                    url: "maintenance/sales/s-lot-sched/update",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    complete: function(jqXhr, textStatus) {
                        if (textStatus == 'success') {
                            /*var grid = vm.GRID.init();
                            grid.dataSource.read();*/
                            vm.GRID.init().dataSource.read();
                            
                            swal("Success", "Lot Remarks is successfully updated!", "success");
                        } else {
                            vm.error(jqXhr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            },
            pageSize: window.uiDefaults.pageSize,
            // batch: true,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "lot_id",
                    fields: {
                        lot_id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                        lot_prod_grp_id: { type: "string" },
                        lot_year: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        lot_code: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        lot_start_date: { 
                            type: "date", 
                            parse: function(value) {
                                return kendo.toString(value, "yyyy-MM-dd");
                            },
                            validation: {
                                custom: function(input) {
                                    if (input.is("[name='lot_start_date']") && input.val().length == 0) {
                                        input.attr("data-custom-msg", "Start date is required.");
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        lot_remarks: { 
                            type: "string",
                            validation: {
                                lotremarks_min_validate: function (input) {
                                    if (input.is("[name='lot_remarks']") && input.val().length < 4 && input.val().length != 0) {
                                        input.attr("data-lotremarks_min_validate-msg", "Lot Remarks minimum input value is 4.");
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                },
                                lotremarks_max_validate: function (input) {
                                    if (input.is("[name='lot_remarks']") && input.val().length > 100 && input.val().length != 0 ) {
                                        input.attr("data-lotremarks_max_validate-msg", "Lot Remarks maximum input value is 100.");
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                },
                            },

                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
        scrollable: false,
        filterable: window.uiDefaults.filterable,
        pageable: window.uiDefaults.pageable,
        sortable: window.uiDefaults.sortable,
        noRecords: true,
        messages: {
            noRecords: window.uiDefaults.noRecordsMessage,
        },
        selectable: "row",
        /*save: function(e){
            console.log(e);
        },*/
        editable: true,
        toolbar: [ 'save', 'cancel' ],
        columns: [      
        {
            field: "lot_code",
            title: "Lot Code",
            width: 120,
        },
        {
            field: "lot_year",
            title: "Year",
            width: 100,
        },
        {
            field: "lot_start_date",
            title: "Start Date",
            format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",
            width: 120,
        },
        {
            field: "lot_remarks",
            title: "Remarks",
            template: kendo.template($('#lot-remarks-template').html()),
        }],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the attribute name you're adding.

Change the following:

```
input.attr("data-custom-msg", "Start date is required.");
```

To:

```
input.attr("data-lot_start_date-msg", "Start date is required.");
```

Answer (score 0):

So what i did is to change the custom validation to date validation , and create a condition inside the validation to determine if it is empty and if ever it is not in its proper format .